# Can we implement tail recursion modulo cons et al. through trampolines?

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming, compiler-optimization, tailrecursion-modulo-cons

You can regard trampolines as compiler optimizations reified in the program.  So what is stopping us from adapting more general optimization techniques in exactly the same manner.

Here is a sketch of tail recursion *modulo* *`cons`*:

```js
const loop = f => {
  let step = f();

 while (step && step[step.length - 1] && step[step.length - 1].type === recur) {
    let step_ = step.pop();
    step.push(...f(...step_.args));
  }

  return step;
};

const recur = (...args) =>
  ({type: recur, args});

const push = (xs, x) => (xs.push(x), xs);

const map = f => xs =>
  loop((i = 0) =>
    i === xs.length
      ? []
      : push([f(xs[i])], recur(i + 1)));

const xs = 
  map(x => x * 2) (Array(1e6).fill(0).map((x, i) => i))
  .slice(0,5);

console.log(xs); // [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

This kind of optimization depends on the associativity property of an expression. Multiplication is associative too and hence there is tail recursion modulo multiplication. However, I have to cheat to implement it in Javascript:

```js
const loop = f => {
  let step = f();
  const acc = [];

  while (step && step[1] && step[1].type === recur) {
    acc.push(step[0]);
    step = f(...step[1].args);
  }

  return acc.reduce((acc, f) => f(acc), step);
};

const recur = (...args) =>
  ({type: recur, args});

const mul = x => step => [y => x * y, step];

const pow = (x_, n_) =>
  loop((x = x_, n = n_) =>
    n === 0 ? 1
    : n === 1 ? x
    : mul(x) (recur(x, n - 1)));
    
console.log(
  pow(2, 1e6)); // Infinity, no stack overflow
```

As you can see I cannot use a regular `mul`, which isn't particular satisfying. Is this connected with Javascript beeing a strict language? Is there a better way to achieve tail recursion modulo multiplication in JS without having to introduce awkward binary operators?

Comment: see also https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/tail_mod_cons.html, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/tail-recursion-modulo-context-an-equational-approach/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `loop`/`recur` (which I consider an ugly and unnecessary hack), consider using folds:

```js
const recNat = (zero, succ) => n => {
    let result = zero;

    while (n > 0) {
        result = succ(result);
        n = n - 1;
    }

    return result;
};

const mul = x => y => x * y;

const pow = x => recNat(1, mul(x));

console.log([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,1e6].map(pow(2))); // [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,Infinity]
```

Almost every recursive function can be defined using folds (a.k.a. structural recursion, a.k.a. induction). For example, even the [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) can be defined using folds:

```js
const recNat = (zero, succ) => n => {
    let result = zero;

    while (n > 0) {
        result = succ(result);
        n = n - 1;
    }

    return result;
};

const add = x => y => x + y;

const ack = recNat(add(1),
    ackPredM => recNat(ackPredM(1),
        ackMPredN => ackPredM(ackMPredN)));

console.time("ack(4)(1)");
console.log(ack(4)(1)); // 65533
console.timeEnd("ack(4)(1)");
```

The above code snippet takes about 18 seconds to compute the answer on my laptop.

Now, you might ask why I implemented `recNat` using iteration instead of natural recursion:

```js
const recNat = (zero, succ) => function recNatZS(n) {
    return n <= 0 ? zero : succ(recNatZS(n - 1));
};
```

I used iteration for the same reason you used iteration to implement `loop`. Trampolining. By implementing a different trampoline for every data type you're going to fold, you can write functional code without having to worry about stack overflows.

**Bottom line:** Use folds instead of explicit recursion. They are a lot more powerful than you think.

Comment: I was blindfolded. This is a whole new world to explore. Thank you for not turning your back on this odd, clumsy language and its community.

Comment: _By implementing a different trampoline for every data type_ - it's a typeclass, right? Finally, Javascript gets its very own typeclass.

Comment: I don't fully understand it but it seems to depend on monoids. I'll investigate.

Comment: No, type classes are an entirely different topic. Type classes are used for [ad hoc polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism), which has nothing to do with folds. A fold is an elimination rule of a data type. Every data type has introduction rules (i.e. rules for creating values of that data type) and elimination rules (i.e. rules for using/consuming values of that data type). For example, consider the `List` data type which is defined as `data List a = Null | Cons a (List a)`. The introduction rules are `Null` and `Cons`. The elimination rule is `foldr`.

Comment: No, it doesn't depend on monoids. In fact, it has little to do with category theory and a lot to do with type theory.

Comment: By the way, the reason why folds (at least the way I described them) aren't type classes is because every data type has a different fold. For example, `recNat` for natural numbers, `recList` for lists, etc. However, it is possible to create a polymorphic fold for all data types using an [F-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-algebra). Here's a [good explanation](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/bartosz/understanding-algebras).